# Updation of java encrytion standards from DESede to AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

we have an application related to java which stores password in encrypted form in DB,so we need to decrypt and and use it for authenticating , and again encrypt passwords and store in Db for new user creation.Its basically we using encyption/decrption standards for password validations.It was originally implemented using DESede algorithm.So, we need to update those ecryption standards from desede to some new standards, So any one suggest updated standard for DESede .

I am thinking of AES-256 algorithm, so Any valid suggestion.

Comment: Is there a good reason for encrypting the passwords instead of using a hash to authenticate?

Comment: Ours is like entitlement management application, requires high security for user authentication,so need to encrpt and decrypt the passwrds

Answer (score 2):

As with any encryption / security stuff, it's easy to get that wrong.
You should look at existing standards / implementations.
For your task of "securing a password", consider RFC 2898 / PKCS#5 PBKDF2.
Check out http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2898.html and http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2127

You probably do not actually want to *encrypt* the password. You want to *shroud* them. One known way to do this is to apply *seeded and iterated hashing*. Make sure that you have no way to get at the passwords **yourself**. Otherwise anyone who can read your data(base) will have an easy job. Given a used ID and a password and the seed, you re-apply the shrouding, then compare the results.

Of course, there are ways to turn a block cipher into a one-way function, and maybe your system already does that properly. If so, a plain replacement of the block cipher could probably be OK.